# How can I have UNION respect column aliases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sorry for the bad title, I couldn't think of anything better. Feel free to edit.

I have to work with a db table that uses one column to store different types of information (last name if person, company name if company). A nightmare, I know, but it's what it is.

To distinguish the meaning, there is another column with an integer that specifies the type of what's in the name column.

The schema of this table looks as follows (simplified):

```
ID int
dtype int
name varchar(50)
```

So, a sample could look like this:

```
ID       dtype       name
---------------------------
1        0           Smith
2        0           Trump
3        1           ABC Ltd.
4        1           XYZ Ltd.
```

I'm trying to normalize this using the following T-SQL code:

```
WITH companies AS 
 (
  SELECT ID, name AS company 
  FROM nametable WHERE dtype=1
  ),
      people AS 
  (
  SELECT ID, name AS person 
  FROM nametable WHERE dtype=0
  ),
  SELECT * FROM companies UNION ALL SELECT * FROM people;
```

What I hoped to get is a new table with the schema:

```
ID
dtype
company
person
```

Or, in table view:

```
ID       dtype       person        company
------------------------------------------
1        0           Smith
2        0           Trump
3        1                         ABC Ltd.
4        1                         XYZ Ltd.
```

Instead, the field is now just called `person` instead of `name` but it's still just one field for 2 types of information.

I understand I could just create a new table and insert each partial result into it but it seems there should be a simpler way. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: share sample input and output

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is: you don't. Column names are taken from the first source in the union(s). All of the rows must have one schema, i.e. the same data types in the same order (though the column names may differ). If you want to split one column into several you'll need to use one of the techniques demonstrated in the answers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment HABO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need case when which helps you

```
   select ID, dtype,case when dtype=0 then name end AS company,
   case when dtype=1 then name end  AS person
   FROM nametable
```

The CASE statement goes through conditions and return a value when condition is met, from your sample input and output its clear you want to create type wise new column ,so i used case Statement

Comment: While this helped me a lot, it would be great for future reference if you could elaborate a bit on `case when` and why it's the solution here.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `UNION` for this at all. A better approach would be using a bit of aggregation.

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN dtype = 0 THEN [name] END) AS company
       MAX(CASE WHEN dtype = 1 THEN [name] END) AS person 
FROM nametable
GROUP BY ID;
```

`UNION (ALL)` doesn't "care" for aliases though. It combines the datasets it receives into 1. All the datasets must have the same definition and the dataset returned will have the same definition. If the datasets have different aliases for columns, the aliases supplied in the first dataset will be used. `UNION` doesn't detect that the datasets have different names for the columns and therefore return the different names as different columns; that's not what a `UNION` does.

*Edit: well this will give the OP the data they want, however, there's no need for the aggregation. I was honestly expected ID's to be a shared resource; because that's **normally** the only time you have such horrid tables. The fact that it isn't just makes this table even more confused...*

Comment: Trust me, the table gets a lot more confusing than that. :) Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want three columns in the output, you'll have to have three columns in each UNION ALL subquery. Add NULL columns so the columns line up correctly, and make sure the first UNION ALL subquery names the columns correctly.

Example:

```
WITH
  companies AS (
    SELECT
      ID,
      dtype,
      name AS company,
    FROM nametable WHERE dtype=1
  ),
  people AS (
    SELECT
      ID,
      dtype,
      name AS person
    FROM nametable WHERE dtype=0
  )
-- Inserting the dummy columns where the UNION ALL is,
-- so I can keep the WITH CTEs simple.
-- I could also have put the dummy columns in the CTE,
-- then this could have been SELECT *.
SELECT ID, dtype, company, NULL as person FROM companies
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, dtype, NULL,    person         FROM people;
```

This will give the output you desire:

```
ID       dtype       person        company
------------------------------------------
1        0           Smith
2        0           Trump
3        1                         ABC Ltd.
4        1                         XYZ Ltd.
```